# if file_exists echo from database else dont do anything

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am sure this would be a quick fix but I haven't been able to find anything by searching SO and google.

I am trying to create a website with php that will output results from a MySQL database. One of my rows in my database does not have a value but when I run the following code it still trys to output an image.

```
<p><?php echo $row['product_desc'] ?></p>
<p><img src="
    <?php echo $row["product_img_name"] ?>" height="133" width="100"></p>
<p><span class="price"><?php echo $row['price'] ?></span></p>
```

Right now I have 10 items in my database and all but one has a value for product_img_name. It still fills the output with a blank broken link for the image where that one field is empty. What would eb the correct way to do this to make it skip the line. I have attempted to use an if statement

```
<p><?php echo $row['product_desc'] ?></p>
<p><img src="
    <?php if file_exists($product_img_name) {echo $row["product_img_name"]} ?>" height="133" width="100"></p>
<p><span class="price"><?php echo $row['price'] ?></span></p>
```

but that returns an error.

Does anyone know how I may be able to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You should provide the error. I'd guess you need `if (file_exists($product_img_name)) {` This also is going to generate an `img` element on regardless of if it exists or not.

Comment: That didn't work. The error I am receiving is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: If the names of the image files are exactly what's stored in the table too, then there are two possible ways to write a check: (1) `if (file_exists($row["product_img_name"]))` or (2) `if(isset($row["product_img_name"]) && $row["product_img_name"] > "")`

Comment: I tried this and also the other way but didnt work. Gave me the same error as previous.

<p><img src="
        <?php if(isset($row["product_img_name"]) && $row["product_img_name"] > ""){ echo $row["product_img_name"]} ?>" height="133" width="100"></p>

Comment: You made a syntax error. The condition to be checked belongs into parentheses: `if (...stuff...) {...do things}`. You have `if ...stuff... { ...do things}`.

Comment: I fixed that with my last try but I am still receiving the error. I tried what Dhruv Saxena said to try.

Comment: I tried this by adding the ; 

<?php if (file_exists($row["product_img_name"])){ echo $row["product_img_name"];} ?>" height="133" width="100"></p>

But I am now back to my original problem...with it filling in a broken link "image"

I want it to return nothing if the file doesnt exists in the database and move on to fill in the data.

Comment: You need to end the `echo` line. `echo $row["product_img_name"];`.

Comment: chris85 I did end it. Not in the original but the other one that I tried from Dhruv. It "worked" but still shows a broken link.

Comment: <p><img src="
        <?php if (file_exists($row["product_img_name"])){ echo $row["product_img_name"];} ?>" height="133" width="100"></p>

Comment: Broken link or an error? You need to describe the exact issue. As I noted this will always generate an `img` element.

Comment: Broken Link.

The web page is [link](http://www.carterandjasper.com/index.php)

Second item on the list in my database doesnt have an image.

Comment: You need to move the `if` before the `<img` creation. The `img` makes the element. Your conditional currently only affects the output of the URL for the source.

Comment: but the if is part of the php statement not the html?

Comment: Yea, move it above the HTML, or you can have the PHP output HTML. Use the `@` to tag.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks! I will take a look at it a little later. I have to get going but will tag you later tonight when I get a chance to look at it again.

Comment: @chris85 I just tried
    
<p><?php if (file_exists($row["product_img_name"])) ?><img src="
        <?php echo $row["product_img_name"]; ?>" height="133" width="100"></p>

and I still have the broken link for the image.